# «Property 'next' of object # is not a function» — как исправить?

Tags: node.js, express

```
// Users
 router.get('/users', checkAuth, require('./users/').get);
```

-

```
var Users = require('../../../models/users.js').Users,
HttpMessage = require('../../../components/error/').HttpMessage,
moment = require('moment'),
async = require('async');

exports.get = function(req, res) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            Users.find({}).populate('_group', 'name').exec(callback);
        },
        function(users, callback){
            res.render('./pages/users', {
                pageName : 'users',
                pageNameRu : 'Список пользователей',
                users: users,
                moment: moment
            });
        }
    ]);
};
```

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Если же убрать:

```
.populate('_group', 'name')
```

, то ошибки не будет.

```
Users.find({}).populate('_group', 'name').exec(callback);
```

- запрос выполняется и populate работает, данные получаем, но не рендерится страница(скриншот ошибки выше)

Answer (score 1):

Вы немного запутались в асинхронных вызовах. `async.waterfall` возвращает управление сразу. 
Попробуйте так.

```
module.exports.get = function(req, res, next) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            Users.find({}).populate('_group', 'name').exec(callback);
        },
        function(users, callback){
            res.render('./pages/users', {
                pageName : 'users',
                pageNameRu : 'Список пользователей',
                users: users,
                moment: moment
            }, callback);
        },
        function(html, callback){
          res.send(html);
          callback();
        }
    ], next);
};
```

Использование этой функции останется каким было

```
// Users
router.get('/users', checkAuth, require('./users/').get);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, но это не помогло , та же ошибка.

Comment: Ух. Пропустил `callback`. А так?

Comment: Увы, но нет. До callback (который вы добавили) дело даже не доходит, ошибка именно на res.render;

Comment: А так? `res.render()` с callback

Comment: res.render() - даже так

Comment: Уже не знаю что предложить. Может заменить `res.render()` `req.app.render()`. Очень странно

Comment: Есть такой полезный инструмент для отладки `node-inspector` https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector, позволяющий отлаживать node-программы из Chrome. Попробуйте "прошагать" этот код в нём. Может быть, ошибка в другом месте.